# Jquery: Switch pictures of a draggable at the exact same position

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I am coding a little game for fun and practice where the user has to throw stones on a politician using drag and drop. First, the user has to drag the politician into a trash can and then throw the stones.
After the politician got hit 5 times I want the image of the politician change without changing the position. I've managed to store the position of the dragged politician but when I replace the picture it always appears somewhere else.

Here is my code for the draggable `.politician` where I store the position in the variable:

```
$(function() {
    $('.politician').draggable({scroll: false, revert: "invalid"});
    $('.stone').draggable({scroll: false});    
    $('.trashdiv').droppable({
        accept: '.politician',
        drop: function(event, ui) { 
            var left = ui.position.top;
            var top = ui.position.left;      
            $("<div>Nice! Now throw things on the politician</div>").dialog();              
        }
});
```

And here on the last else if-statement I want the picture of the draggable .politician changed but remain at the same position as the user dragged it.

```
var limit = 5;
var hit1 = 1;
var hit2 = 2;
var hit3 = 3;
var hit4 = 4;
var counter = 0;

 $('.politician').droppable({
    accept: '.stone',
    drop: function(event, div) { 
        div.draggable.remove();
        counter++;

        if (counter == hit1) {
            alert("Awesome! You're doing it right.");
        }

        else if (counter == hit2) {
            alert("Outch! That must hurt!");
        }


        else if (counter == hit3) {
            alert("Keep going!");
        }


        else if (counter == hit4) {
            alert("Get it all out there!");
        }

        else if (counter == limit) {
               $(this).droppable("disable"),
         $( ".politician" ).replaceWith("<img src='pics/frauke-petry-dead-final.png' width='30%'> You've defeated the politician! Good Job");
```